# How can I execute a local script from remote computer with parameters

Tags: powershell, network-printers

I'm trying to find a way to run a PowerShell script located on my pc from remote computer.

I need to be able to clear the print queue of random network printer from any pc in our domain.

I have a little script located on my pc (example mypc01) and I need to be able to execute it from some other pc (example somepc01) and pass the parameter like :

$printservername("1prinsrv") & $printername("hp00014")

**Problem** : pc's from where I need to launch this script don't have admin rights(not an issue as I can use launch as), pc's don't have latest PowerShell installed (big issue as commands I need to execute don't exist in older version of PowerShell)

Script :

```
 $printername = Read-Host "give the printername in please"
 $servername = Read-Host "give the servername in please"
 Get-PrintJob -ComputerName $servername -PrinterName $printername | ` where         JobStatus -like "Error*","Paused*" | Remove-PrintJob
```

Can someone please help me to find the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have PowerShell version 3.0 or newer on your own machine, you can use `Invoke-Command` with the `-FilePath` and `-ArgumentList` parameters, but first you'll need to rewrite your script to support parameter binding:

```
param(
    [string]$PrinterName = $(Read-Host "Input printer name"),
    [string]$ServerName = $(Read-Host "Input server name")
)

Get-PrintJob -ComputerName $servername -PrinterName $printername | Where {
  $_.JobStatus -like "Error*" -or $_.JobStatus -like "Paused*" 
} | Remove-PrintJob
```

Now we can do:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName anypc01 -FilePath C:\ClearPrintQueue.ps1 -ArgumentList "printer123","printerserver01"
```

---

The other way around (invoking a local script on your computer from a remote one), you can do:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mypc {
    C:\ClearPrintQueue.ps1 -PrinterName "printer123"
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks! for your help
I need to start this command from anypc(anypc execut command on mypc)I try to modify it a little, however still not rly working
Invoke-Command -ComputerName pcname01 -FilePath \\pcname01\C$\Temp\pq.ps1 -ArgumentList "printername"
,"servername"The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid.  Names may not contain ',' or '\' charac
ters.
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_PrintJob:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_PrintJob) [Get-PrintJob], CimExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Get-PrintJob
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to supply the Server name as well

Comment: I hardcoded servername for test porposes and modifyed your script to : 
param(
    [string]$printername = $(Read-Host "Input printer name")
)
And I know that server and printername are correct
Invoke-Command -ComputerName pcname01 -FilePath \\pcname01\C$\Temp\pq.ps1 -ArgumentList printername

Comment: Running the script on my pc work flawlessly, but not if I try from another pc.... :(

Comment: even if I make all variables hardcodded give me exact same error message when I try it from remote pc.....